# Why did my Quick Launch icons become sorted by name?

Tags: windows-xp

Suddenly all my quick launch icons are sorted by name.

I must have done something odd but what?
Can I stop it from happening again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Auto Arrange is turned off.

Right click somewhere on the desktop > Arrange Icons By > Auto Arrange - shouldn't be ticked.

Comment: I don't have a "Arrange Icons By" menu when I right-click my quick launch bar

Comment: @Nifle , Right click on the empty space of your quick launch and click on open .and then follow ChrisF

Comment: He meant that you should open the folder of quick launch, then in Explorer right-click on empty space inside the right-hand pane and uncheck Arrange Icons By -> Auto Arrange.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [annoyances.org](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/win98/t1009758382):

> Start and new text file in some text
>   editor (e.g. notepad) and paste the
>   following text:
>
> ---- Start COPY below this line ----
>   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
>   "NoSaveSettings"=hex:00,00,00,00
>   ---- End COPY above this line ----
>
> Save this file as NoSaveSettings.reg,
>   navigate to the file and double-click
>   on it.  This will update your registry
>   with the correct value. Logout and
>   login again, and you should see the
>   effect.

Needless to say: Take a backup of the registry (or a restore point) before monkeying with it.

Comment: It already have that value